# How do you resize the shapes drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to resize the shapes drawn on a canvas.  I want them to be resized using mouse events on canvas like in paint.  The image should show a get grid when it is being resized, so that we can drag it to resize it in the size we want  Please help me in this.

Comment: This needs a lot more information, how are you drawing them now for instance?  You want a grid to show up?  Like in photoshop or something?

Comment: yes in the similar manner so that we can drag that image from the edges to whatever size we want

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to redraw the scene making your object smaller or larger. Animate it. You'll probably want to listen to mouseclick and mousemove events and when a drag action is recognized by your script the animation that redraws a region of your canvas should start. I'm almost certain there's no way of moving or resizing an object that has been drawn on a canvas.

Comment: Basically this. There are *no* objects on a canvas. There are just dots of colour. If you want to save objects, then you need to store your own shape objects and keep redrawing them, and keep listening for clicks and drags, to know when to change your object's size/position based on where the mouse clicks/moves.